# Why does the '!!' shortcut fail to execute the previously run command?

Tags: command-line, bash, bash-history

Recently I typed at my terminal

```
username:~$ !!
```

and got error from *bash*:

```
bash: !!: command not found
```

At the same time, it succeeds when done under superuser.

I investigated my user's PATH's content and found nothing suspicious:

```
/home/username/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
```

Here is output of:

```
username:~$ history | tail
1993  date
1994  cal
1995  vcal
1996  uptime
1997  uname
1998  uptime
1999  uname
2000  uptime
2001  uname
2002  history | tail
```

Another:

```
username:~$ echo foo
foo
username:~$ !!
bash: !!: command not found
```

Comment: Does it always happen? What if you run `echo foo` and then `!!`? Also, please [edit] your question and add the output of `history | tail` or so. Does your shell session have any history?

Comment: What is your input language ? Are you using standard english or some other keyboard ?

Comment: Is `histexpand` set in your shell options? what is the output of `echo $-`?

Comment: I'm curious: how did history expansion come to be disabled?

Comment: @muru, ...speaking as a former freenode #bash regular, I used to spend a lot of time advising folks to disable it, without getting any pushback from other channel elders -- people being surprised by commands with `!` literals not being honored without extra quoting was a much more common occurrence than finding someone who wanted history expansion functionality not available in easier-to-use form through readline.

Comment: @muru, I disabled it in the middle of my configuration file when was copying blindly .bashrc content from one of many example files I found on the internet.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

History expansion might be disabled:

```
$ echo foo
foo
$ !!
echo foo
foo
$ set +o histexpand
$ set -o | grep hist
histexpand      off
history         on
$ echo foo
foo
$ !!
bash: !!: command not found
```

Try `set -H` or `set -o histexpand`.

Comment: @Serg `set -o`, or the special variable `$-`

Comment: OK, I see, that's what you're doing with `set -o | grep hist`